# WinAPI: поиск файлов по маске и получение полного пути

Tags: c++, winapi

Подскажите как можно решить следующую проблему

1. пользователь вводит некоторую маску для поиска, например `d:\folder\file*.tx*`
2. осуществляется поиск

например:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA findData;
HANDLE fileHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

fileHandle = ::FindFirstFile(maskPath.c_str(), &findData);

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == fileHandle)
    return false;

do
{
    // не рассматривать папки
    if (findData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        continue;

    // получить полный путь

} while (::FindNextFile(fileHandle, &findData) != 0);

::FindClose(fileHandle);
```

и надо получить полный путь найденного файла

В структуре `WIN32_FIND_DATA` содержится лишь имя файла и это было бы приемлемо, если бы поисковая маска была известна (например `path + \*.*`), тогда можно было бы получить полный путь самому.

Но как быть в общем случае?

Может лучше вообще уйти от WinAPI в сторону голого stl? Есть же функционал поиска в нем вроде как, хотя бы в последних версиях

Comment: `FindFile` допускает маску только в имени файла. Соответственно путь папки можно извлечь без проблем.

Comment: @user7860670, понял, а если маску потребуется делать по всему полному пути? конечно можно и итерационно задачу решить, но есть ли в stl встроенные стредства?

Comment: Маску по полному пути придется разбирать самостоятельно, по одной папке за раз. В стандартной библиотеке есть средства перебирания содержимого папок.

Answer (score 0):

Функция `GetFullPathName()` извлекает полный путь и имя указанного файла